# Boolean operation to combine the booleans in an input and a trigger

Tags: python, pandas, boolean, conditional-statements, boolean-expression

Here is some sample data with an "input" column and a "trigger" column. The "input" column is generally False but has True segments (e.g. one True segment in the sample data). I am trying to create a third column ("output") that is a modified version of the "input" column. Essentially the True segments in "output" should begin earlier than in "input", as indicated by the "trigger" (by the previous True value of the "trigger"). I want to achieve this with vector operations and I want to avoid loops e.g. for.

```
index = pd.date_range('2020-01-01', '2020-01-13', freq='D')
columns = ['Input', 'Trigger']
data = [[False, False],
        [False, False],
        [False, True],
        [False, False],
        [False, False],
        [False, True],
        [False, False],
        [False, False],
        [True, False],
        [True, False],
        [True, False],
        [True, False],
        [False, False]
       ]
pd.DataFrame(data, index, columns)
```

I don't know how to achieve my purpose but the result with the sample data I provided would look like this:

```
columns = ['Input', 'Trigger', 'Output']
data = [[False, False, False],
        [False, False, False],
        [False, True, False],
        [False, False, False],
        [False, False, False],
        [False, True, True],
        [False, False, True],
        [False, False, True],
        [True, False, True],
        [True, False, True],
        [True, False, True],
        [True, False, True],
        [False, False, False]
       ]
pd.DataFrame(data, index, columns)
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can vectorize this operation.

Comment: I don't follow the logic. Shouldn't the "output" in the third row be `True`?

Comment: Is there only one stretch of True in Input? Can there be a True in Trigger after (or during) the stretch in Input? Then what should happen?

Comment: Why is the "trigger" in the 3rd row ignored? Why is the final row false? Imagine that we know nothing about what it is you are attempting to do other than what you explicitly tell us.

Comment: No, there are multiple stretches of True in Input although the sample data only shows one. The only thing that matters really is the True stretches in Input, which should start earlier in Output as indicated by the previous trigger. Otherwise nothing else happens and Output equals False like in Input.

Comment: You didn't comment on what happens if a True in Trigger is within a stretch

Comment: @mozway: If there is a True in Trigger within a True stretch in Input, we ignore it. That is what your solution is doing as far as I can tell. Thank you, it's brilliant!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Trigger column to create groups, then split and backfill the Input.

```
df['Output'] = (
 df['Input']
 .replace({False: None})
 .groupby(df['Trigger'].cumsum()).bfill()  # backfill previous NA in group
 .fillna(False)
)
```

output:

```
            Input  Trigger  Output
2020-01-01  False    False   False
2020-01-02  False    False   False
2020-01-03  False     True   False
2020-01-04  False    False   False
2020-01-05  False    False   False
2020-01-06  False     True    True
2020-01-07  False    False    True
2020-01-08  False    False    True
2020-01-09   True    False    True
2020-01-10   True    False    True
2020-01-11   True    False    True
2020-01-12   True    False    True
2020-01-13  False    False   False
```

*NB. this does not account for the case where there is a trigger within a stretch as the expected behavior is unclear*